# Can components be temporarily registered in an Autofac container?

Tags: autofac

I'm building a plugin for a 3rd party application and my plugin uses Autofac to wire up various components.  The container is built at application startup, but the host application invokes my commands at a later time.

When a command is invoked, the host application provides a few instances of types that it defines and that my components will need to use.  I'd like to register these instances in the container so that it can take care of wiring up the components that depend on these instances.

I'm aware that I can use a ContainerBuilder to update an existing container, but I'd like to remove these registrations when the command has completed as these instances will no longer be valid.  Is this possible?

Maybe a better approach is to use 2 containers... The command could create a new container to register these instances and other components could be resolved from the application scoped container.

How could I hook up the 2 containers so that resolve calls bubble up to the application scoped container?

Are there any gotchas to be aware of with this approach?  I imagine there may be component lifetime issues...

**Edit:**  Now I've done a bit more research and testing and and it turns out I can just use the BeginLifetimeScope(Action<ContainerBuilder>) overload to register the host application provided instances for the nested lifetime only.  For some reason I thought that adding registrations to the nested lifetime would result in them being added to the root container but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Yes, a LifetimeScope is exactly what you want in this case.   Please post an answer to your question and mark it as accepted so people finding this question later get the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to post my answer earlier but SO said I had to wait 8 hours because I don't have enough reputation points yet...

Comment: Yay! I can now post my answer but can't accept it until tomorrow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in my edit above, it turns out that BeginLifetimeScope(Action<ContainerBuilder>) is exactly what I need.  For some reason I thought that adding registrations to the nested lifetime would result in them being added to the root container and therefore being resolvable after the nested lifetime scope ends, but that doesn't seem to be the case.